# Find a list of elements in the arrays

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7

I'm working on my python script to get a list of elements in the arrays. I'm using the variable `position_x = elem.getX()` to get the list of elements for the pixels size.

So when I try this:

```
for elem in self.program_buttons:
    position_x = elem.getX()    #Get positionX
    #print the list of elements with 375
    print position_x
```

I will get the result like this:

```
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 375
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 724
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 1073
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 1261
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 1449
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 1798
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 2147
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 2496
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 2845
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 3194
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 3543
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 4241
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 4590
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 4939
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 5289
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 5638
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 5987
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 6336
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 6685
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 7034
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 7383
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 7732
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 9456
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 10154
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 10503
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 10852
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 11201
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 11550
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 11900
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 12249
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 12598
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 12947
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 13296
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 13645
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 13994
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 14343
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 14692
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 15041
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 15390
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 15739
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 16088
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 16437
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 18161
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 18860
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 19209
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 19558
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 19907
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 20256
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 20605
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 20954
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 21652
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 22001
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 22350
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 22699
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 23048
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 23397
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 23746
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 24095
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 24444
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 24794
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 25143
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 26867
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 27565
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 27914
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 28263
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 28612
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 28961
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 29310
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 29659
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 375
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 1073
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 1261
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 1449
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 2147
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 3871
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 4220
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 4918
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 5616
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 5965
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 8374
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 8723
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 9072
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 9421
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 9770
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 10468
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 12192
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 13916
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 14614
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 14963
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 15661
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 16011
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 16709
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 17407
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 19473
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 19822
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 21546
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 22244
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 22593
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 23291
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 23989
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 24338
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 26747
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 27096
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 27445
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 27794
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 28143
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 28841
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 30565
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 32289
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 32987
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 33336
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 34035
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 34384
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 35082
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 35780
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 37504
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 37853
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 38202
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 38551
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 38900
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 39249
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 39598
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 39947
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 40296
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 40995
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 41693
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 42042
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 44450
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 44799
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 45148
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 45497
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 45846
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 46544
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 48268
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 49992
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 50691
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 51040
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 51738
18:32:12 T:4060  NOTICE: 375
...etc
```

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
375
375
375
375
375
375
375
```

Can you please tell me how I can find the elements of `375` in the arrays using the variable `position_x` so I can print a list of elements with `375`?

**EDIT:**

Here is the result for `print type(position_x)`:

```
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
00:22:49 T:6656  NOTICE: <type 'int'>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67282/discussion-on-question-by-rob-find-a-list-of-elements-in-the-arrays).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be what you're getting at.

```
elems = [elem for elem in self.program_buttons if elem.getX() == 375]
for elem in elems:
    # the same code you have before -- the above line filters it
```

Probably more readably:

```
for elem in self.program_buttons:
    position_x = elem.getX()
    if position_x == 375:
        # use the same code you have to print it -- this is your filter
    else:
        continue
    # these last two lines do literally nothing and can be excluded
    # I just find them more readable!!
```

Basically you're filtering your results based on whether the notice number is `375`. My first bit of code gives you a list `elems` that contains every element whose notice passes the filter. The second bit of code produces no such list, simply printing the lines of code that pass.

If you literally only want the output of the `375`s, you could try:

```
elems = [elem for elem in self.program_buttons if elem.getX() == 375]
for elem in elems:
    print(375)
```

or

```
for elem in self.program_buttons:
    position_x = elem.getX()
    if position_x == 375:
        print(375)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I have got an error: `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'endswith'`, the error are jumping on this line `if position_x.endswith("375"):`. Do you know why I get an error?

Comment: @Rob looks like `position_x` isn't a string, it's an int. You seemed incredibly sure that it's a string, so I don't know how to help you.

Comment: oh sorry, it was my mistake. I thought it was a string. I did not realized that it's an int. Do you know how I can get the int with `375`?

Comment: `position_x == 375`? You still haven't listed `type(position_x)` or shown any of the code that generates this (what is `type(elem)`? What is `type(elem).getX`?) so it's hard to give you any advice.

Comment: I have already tried it with `if position_x == 375` which it give me the same result where you can see it on my first question of this post. :(

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to use `type(position_x)`. do i need to use `print type(position_x)` or just `type(position_x)`?

Comment: @Rob please edit your question with the information that I and several other users have requested. Namely: what kind of object is `elem`? What kind of object is `position_x`, and what is the function definition for `elem.getX`?

Comment: I have updated it. did you see it?